# One sided Satisfactory Partition problem

Tags: graph-theory

The Satisfaction Partition problem is to decide if a graph has a vertex partition (U,V) into non empty parts where each vertex has as many neighbours in its part as in the other part. This problem is known to be NP complete.

Now modify the problem so that we seek a vertex partition (U,V) into non empty parts where each vertex of U has as many neighbours in its part as in the other part. Is anything known about this problem? Might it be NP complete also?